# How do I determine if a number is part of the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: ruby

I have an assignment to write a method that determines whether or not a number is part of the Fibonacci sequence.

Going along with the formula:

> a positive integer z is a Fibonacci number if and only if one of 5z^2 + 4 or 5z^2 − 4 is a perfect square

I defined the following method which works for small numbers and large Fibonacci numbers, however, for whatever reason, my assignment specs throw an error when processing a large non-Fibonacci number, specifically when running `is_fibonacci?(927372692193078999171)`. Apparently the method returns `true` instead of `false`. Everything else seems to be correct, so I'm kind of pulling my hair out over why this wouldn't work. Any suggestions?

```
def is_fibonacci?(i)
  bigNumber1 = Math.sqrt((5*(i**2)+4))
  bigNumber2 = Math.sqrt((5*(i**2)-4))
  if bigNumber1 == bigNumber1.round || bigNumber2 == bigNumber2.round
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Floating point operations only have a certain (low) precision. You cannot get around this by rounding.

Comment: What is the goal of your check?  I can't follow it.

Comment: Ah ok. How could I make it more precise? The rounding is purely to figure out whether bigNumber1 or 2 is a perfect square.

Comment: The check is to make sure the method rejects very large non-Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Have you tried using BigDecimal?

Comment: I have not...how would I implement that?

Comment: @BenFlynn: That would probably solve the problem for the given number, but not in general.

Comment: @undur_gongor I don't understand the issue with BigDecimal -- could you elaborate?

Comment: Darshan shows how BigDecimal would work... not sure what the fail case is...

Comment: @DarshanComputing: I refrain from that statement. It works because BigDecimal will always compute the full integer part of the square root (plus some fractional digits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Math.sqrt` returns a floating-point value which is normally just an estimation of the real square root. For large numbers you just get something like 1234567600000.0 which will always be considered an integer by your code.

Implement your own arbitrary-precision, integer square-root function. A naive approach could be like this:

```
def is_fibonacci?(i)
  n1 = 5 * i**2 + 4
  n2 = n1 - 8
  is_square?(n1) or is_square?(n2)
end

# find floor(sqrt(i)) by nesting intervals
def sqrt(i)
  a, b = 0, i
  while a + 1 < b
    m = (a + b) / 2
    if m**2 > i
      b = m
    else
      a = m
    end
  end
  a
end

def is_square?(i)
  s = sqrt(i)
  s ** 2 == i
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick. Is there any way to require a more precise square root result besides defining it yourself though?

Comment: I'm sure there is a lot of code out there implementing the `sqrt` more efficiently. But you cannot do it exactly with floats. Even not with BigDecimal.

Comment: It turned out my statement regarding BigDecimal is wrong. In this case, BigDecimal is not much different from a pure integer solution.

Answer (score 8):

As noted elsewhere, the issue is with the precision of Floats.  [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) provides arbitrary-precision arithmetic:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def is_fibonacci?(i)
  i = BigDecimal.new(i)
  bigNumber1 = (5*(i**2)+4).sqrt(0)
  bigNumber2 = (5*(i**2)-4).sqrt(0)
  return (bigNumber1 == bigNumber1.round || bigNumber2 == bigNumber2.round)
end

is_fibonacci? 927372692193078999171 # => false
is_fibonacci? 927372692193078999176 # => true
```

Comment: @undur_gongor No problem; we're all here to help and learn from each other. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Binet's formula needs the calculation of square root. Here is my solution using built in Bignum and Newton's methods for checking square root.

```
def isSQRT(x)
  return true if [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100].include?x
  z = x / 10  #first guess
  z=z-(z*z-x)/(2*z) while (z-1)**2 > x
  return true if (z-1)**2 == x
  false
end

def is_fibonacci?(num)
  isSQRT(5*num**2+4) || isSQRT(5*num**2-4)
end
```

Also, there is a way to figure out without using Binet, as shown by the [Kenneth's memoization method by Hash](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-cool-Ruby-tricks). So you can check a number by the built-in method of has_value?(number).

```
fibo = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = ( k<=2 ? 1 : h[k-2] + h[k-1] ) }
fibo[500] #=> instant result of Fibonacci!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works just fine with Ruby's core API methods only.  It returns a boolean

```
def fibonacci?(number_sought)
  num = 2
  result = [1, 1]  until num >= number_sought
    result << result[-1] + result[-2]
    if result.include?(number_sought) then break 
    elsif result[-1] > number_sought then return false
    else next
    end
    num += 1
  end
  !!result
end

p fibonacci?(10946)
p fibonacci?(927372692193078999176)
```

If you want to return the arrays:

```
def fibonacci(number_sought)
  num = 2
  result = [1, 1]  until num >= number_sought
    result << result[-1] + result[-2]
    if result.include?(number_sought) then break 
    elsif result[-1] > number_sought then return result
    else next
    end
    num += 1
  end
  result
end
```